# Combine valid values of Seq[ValidatedNel]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following scenario:

```
case class MyString(str: String)

val val1: ValidatedNel[String, MyString] = MyString("valid1").validNel
val val2: ValidatedNel[String, MyString] = MyString("valid2").validNel
val val3: ValidatedNel[String, MyString] = "invalid".invalidNel
val vals = Seq(val1, val2, val3)
//vals: Seq[cats.data.Validated[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],MyString]] = List(Valid(MyString(valid)), Invalid(NonEmptyList(invalid)))
```

At the end I'd like to be able to do a `match` on the result and get any and all errors or all the valid values as a sequence.

My question is: How to convert `Seq[Validated[NonEmptyList[String],MyString]]` into `Validated[NonEmptyList[String],Seq[MyString]]]`

So, my first pass was to implement `Semigroup` for `Seq[MyString]`:

```
implicit val myStringsAdditionSemigroup: Semigroup[Seq[MyString]] = new Semigroup[Seq[MyString]] {
  def combine(x: Seq[MyString], y: Seq[MyString]): Seq[MyString] = x ++ y
}
```

... which works:

```
Seq(val1, val2).map(_.map(Seq(_))).reduce(_ |+| _)
//res0: cats.data.Validated[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],Seq[MyString]] = Valid(List(MyString(valid1), MyString(valid2)))
```

but I need to prepare my data by wrapping all valid values in `Seq`... which feels strange. So, maybe there's a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use anything other than `Seq`, like `Vector` or `List`, you can `sequence` it.

`sequence` basically turns a type constructor inside out. Meaning turning a `F[G[A]]` into an `G[F[A]]`. For that to work, the `F` needs to be a `Traverse` and the `G` needs to be an `Applicative`. Luckily, `Validated` is an `Applicative` and `List` or `Vector` are instances of `Traverse`.

So in the end your code should look something like this:

```
import cats.implicits._

val validatedList: Validated[NonEmptyList[String],List[MyString]]] = 
  vals.sequence
```

**Note**: if this doesn't compile for you, you might need to enable `partial-unification`.

The easiest way to enable `partial-unification`, is to add the `sbt-partial-unification` [plugin](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification).

If you're on Scala 2.11.9 or newer, you can also simply add the compiler flag:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

We from the `cats` team strongly encourage you to have this flag on at all times when using cats, as it makes everything just a lot easier.

Comment: The project I was trying to use that in is a maven project. Does that mean that there's no way of enabling partial unification and therefore using this functionality?

Comment: Nope you can use them just fine, just put the compiler args inside `<args>` which should be inside `<configuration>` :)